# Aggregate jmockit-coverage output with emma coverage output

Tags: ant, jmockit, emma

Is there a way to aggregate code coverage data from jmockit-coverage and emma coverage? I can run the two different coverage steps in two separate junit ant tasks and generate the coverage data in two directories. Just not sure if the coverage outputs from these two are compatible and can be merged to display together.

Answer (score 0):

No, they can't be aggregated into a single HTML report, since these are two different code coverage tools, which know nothing about each other. Of course, someone could create yet another tool which would do that; personally, I don't see much value in it, though.